# How do I run javascript on sublime text 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sublimetext2

I am working on creating a sketching board and was wondering how do I create a JavaScript file in Sublime Text 2. When I save the file, do I just save it as index.js? By doing that, does it mean the file is a JavaScript file?

I have done the following, but it doesn't really work I think. Because I created a button in html/css and wanted to give it a fade effect using jQuery and when I made the code and applied it, nothing happened.

So how do I get JavaScript and HTML to link in Sublime Text 2?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="etchASketch.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src = "etchASketch.js"></script>   
</head>
```

Comment: `*.js` is a javascript file, so yes. you need to save a file (for example, `etchASketch.js`). your jQuery won't work because of the usage of `href` instead of `src`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to create a javascript file in Sublime Text 2.

From the menu bar:

File -> New File

After that from: View -> Syntax -> JavaScript

you simply can choose a javascript file.

[image]

Another simple way :

Create New File in Sublime then save it with **.js** extension like **yourAppName.js**

[image]

Also make sure to put your javascript file in the  appropriate path that you specified in source attribute of `<script>` tag.

Check first image that I included I put my html file and javascript file in the same folder **Todos List** then I can link my javascript file with html page by:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="todos.js"></script>
```

Notice in `src="todos.js"` I didn't put the full path of js file because they are already in the same folder.but if your javascript file in different folder you should put the full path in order to link it with html page.

**Update**:

I checked your project [images album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/168Gj.jpg) and I test it.it worked perfectly and script file linked fine without any errors.

But I found that there is a lack in your CSS file which prevent you from viewing effect of jQuery event on your button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").mouseenter(function(){
      $("button").addClass("highlight");
  }); 
});
```

You should declare `highlight` class on **CSS** file in order to test your jQuery event:

```
.highlight{
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

Check this full test project that worked perfect for your case:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmMNdR

I hope this would solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.

Comment: You're Welcome! if you find my answer useful accept it by pressing correct button.

Comment: @FatimaA. I found your problem and fix it check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes that does work! Thank you so much! But why do I have to declare the highlight class in CSS? Do I have to declare every jQuery event as a class in CSS?

Comment: Because when you trigger jQuery event with $("button").mouseenter(function(){
      $("button").addClass("highlight");
  }); 
you actually added a css class selector to the element button so the event won't work if there is no `.highlight` class in the CSS file 
check the inspect in google chrome to see the differences when you trigger jQuery event on button element.

also check jQuery `.addClass()` event documentation to understand how it work : https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: You are welcome! if you find the answer helpful accept it to be a reference in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

`*.js` is a JavaScript file extension.

There's no `href` attribute on `<script>` tag, that's might be the reason why jQuery isn't working for you. Change `href` to `src`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Okay, so I tried that and still nothing. Do you want to look at my code, maybe there is something wrong with it? I have attached an album below with pictures of the HTML, CSS and javascript code and the last picture is to show that they are all in the same folder too(its the highlighted files) http://imgur.com/a/VLr5t

Answer (score 0):

You might know how `<img>` tag works. The same applies for `<script>` tags too, when it comes to linking stuff. For example when you link an image from YOUR LOCAL COMPUTER, you have to give the location of the file like `<img src="users/name/desktop/image.png">` similarly when you link a script from from your local computer you have to give the file location like `<script src="users/name/desktop/myScriptFile.js"></script>`, Now the same is applied for links outside your computer, Say from this link `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js`, all you have to do is replace that local link to the link outside like:

FROM

```
<script src="users/name/desktop/myScriptFile.js"></script>
```

TO

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and its `src` not `href`

Comment: Okay, so I tried that and still nothing. Do you want to look at my code, maybe there is something wrong with it? I have attached an album below with pictures of the HTML, CSS and javascript code and the last picture is to show that they are all in the same folder too(its the highlighted files) imgur.com/a/VLr5t